# RoR ActionMailer: Page reload slow when sending mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR, have a registration page, with an "email" field. When the user registers a mail is sent successfully to his mail address but the problem is that it takes a while -about 6 - 10 seconds during which period the page is still reloading. Is this normal, is there an optimization option? any help would be appreciated. I'm Using ActionMailer Bundled with RoR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly normal, the user has to wait for the mail to be sent because you include directly in the action.

One dedicated solution is to make mail sending asynchronous with tools such as Delayed Job.

See screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

Comment: Just Implemented that and it works, got another question,i intend to allow the user click on the link sent to their email address to have their account activated, any hint on this?

Comment: Sure I even have a solution for this but you should accept my answer and ask another question :) One at a time!